# How to output logger with coloredlogs in curses window?

Tags: python, logging, curses

I'm trying to create a simple dashboard for my app and want to display logs in curses window.

Also, using solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27774093/how-to-manage-logging-in-curses) cause same problem.

```
import curses
import logging
import coloredlogs
import os

os.environ['COLOREDLOGS_LOG_FORMAT'] ='%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d %(name)s - %(message)s'
os.environ['COLOREDLOGS_DATE_FORMAT'] ='%H%M%S'

logger = logging.getLogger("Test")

coloredlogs.install(level='DEBUG')

class CursesHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, win, level=logging.DEBUG):
        logging.Handler.__init__(self, level)
        self.win = win

    def emit(self, record):
        self.win.addstr(record.getMessage())
        self.win.refresh()

def main(scrn):

    handler = CursesHandler(scrn.subwin(5,80, 19,0))
    logger.addHandler(handler)

    win = scrn.subwin(10,80, 0,0)

    for i in range(0,10):
        curses.delay_output(250)
        logger.info("Now i = %s", i)
    win.getch()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    curses.wrapper(main)
```

This code results in this:
[image]

Moreover, if I have another panels, logs just overwrites them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to manage logging in curses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27774093/how-to-manage-logging-in-curses)

Comment: Offhand, it seems your `__init__` call is the place to start.

Comment: @ThomasDickey, I tried this already and result is same. Log shows up like in screenshot and overwrites curses layout.

Comment: Can You explain what may cause the problem, because I have no experience in curses and logging handling?

Comment: The apparent problem is that your handler is actually not capturing the logger output; that's going to the standard output which is staircasing because curses has set the terminal to raw mode (and turning `onlcr` off, for instance: "man stty" for **that**).